# R: Wide to long format for dataframe with one single row and >250 columns

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, long-format-data, wide-format-data

I am trying to get my dataframe in a long format. Currently, it's a dataframe with 1 obs. and >250 variables which looks something like this:

| user_0_id | user_0_name | user_0_sex | user_1_id | user_1_name | user_1_sex | user_2_id | user_2_name | user_2_sex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | miller | female | 52 | smith | male | 33 | frank | female |

Meanwhile, I just wish to create a dataframe which looks like this:

| id | name | sex |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | miller | female |
| 52 | smith | male |
| 33 | frank | female |

I've tried renaming the column names in the df to match by applying the following code

```
names(df) <- sub('^users_', '', names(df))
names(df) <- sub('^[0-9.]+', '', names(df))
names(df) <- sub('^_', '', names(df))
```

Afterwards, I've been trying to switch it to the long format using melt, which only ended up either multiplying the obs. or completely mumbling up the dataframe.

```
df <- melt(setDT(df), id.vars = c("id","name"), variable.name = "data")

df <- melt(df, id.vars=c("id", "name", "sex"))
```

This is the first time I've asked a question on stackoverflow, so any advice as to how to make future questions more comprehensible are very welcome! Thanks to anyone that took their time to read this.

Comment: Are there actual duplicates in column names (e.g. `user_1_id` appears twice in the example), or is it a typo where the column numbering continues as expected (`user_2_id`, `user_3_id`, and so on)?

Comment: Hi @Aurèle - no, that was my mistake! There are no duplicate users in this table. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyr)

pivot_longer(
  df,
  cols = everything(),
  names_to = c(".value"),
  names_pattern = "user_\\d+_(.*)"
)
```

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
     id name   sex   
  <int> <chr>  <chr> 
1    16 miller female
2    52 smith  male  
3    33 frank  female
```

---

Where `df` is:

```
df <- read.table(text = 
'user_0_id  user_0_name user_0_sex  user_1_id   user_1_name user_1_sex  user_2_id   user_2_name user_2_sex
16  miller  female  52  smith   male    33  frank   female
', header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use function pivot_longer from package tidyr (https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html)

```
longdf <- widedf %>% pivot_longer(cols=c("variable1", "variable2", 
                                 "variable3", "variable4"),
                    names_to='newvariablename',
                    values_to='newvaluenames')
```

It may be a longer way and first you need to do it for one variable, such as sex, and then again for other class of variables like names. Maybe someone will know a faster way to do it.